# Can Random Variables be written $P(X)$ instead of $P(X=x)$ as a shorthand?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, random-variables, bayesian-network

[Recently I asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839104/can-random-variables-be-conditioned-in-a-cycle) and used the shorthand $P(A)$ for a random variable $A$ to quickly reason about conditional probabilities. However, I was informed that this must be written $P(A=a)$ for random variables and the notational shorthand does not make sense, and is only for events. Is this true?

In particular, I am interested in Bayesian Networks and want to write a factorisation such as
$$P(A,B,C) = P(A)P(B\mid A)P(C\mid A,B) = P(A)P(B)P(C\mid A,B)$$
to say that the structure of the Bayesian Network is a graph with two root nodes corresponding to $A$ and $B$ which are not dependent on any other random variable and a third node corresponding to $C$ which is dependent on $A$ and $B$ (represented by directed edges).

Must I instead write

$$P(A=a,B=b,C=c) = P(A=a)P(B=b\mid A=a)P(C=c\mid A=a,B=b) = P(A=a)P(B=b)P(C=c\mid A=a,B=b)$$

to be mathematically coherent? Would I need to say this is for each $a,b,c$?

Edit: An example I am particularly interested in is on page 3 of [this document](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jtc5/BioinformaticsCourse2001/MurphyBayesNetIntro.pdf), or equivalently the [wikipedia entry for the chain rule of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)). Is it valid to write the chain rule of probability like this?

Edit: I am particularly confused as so much of the literature of Bayesian Networks seems to use this shorthand, such as [this](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_148.html), [this](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/barbados/heckerman.pdf), [this](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jtc5/BioinformaticsCourse2001/MurphyBayesNetIntro.pdf), [this](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518279/building-bayesian-networks-causality-and-cyclic-reasoning?rq=1), and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112566/how-to-compute-this-conditional-probability-in-bayesian-networks).

Comment: No, $P(A)$ has sense only if $A$ is an event. For r.v., you must write $P\{A\in \mathcal A\}$

Comment: Actually, as $X$ is already the random variable, $P(X)$ is hardly a shorthand for a random variable

Comment: If you defined a function $p(x)$ like $p(x)=P(X=x)$ then $p(X)$ would be meaningful.

Comment: Strictly speaking that wouldn't be the case, since your syntax would imply that $ p(X) = P(X = X) = 1 $ with probability 1. But I agree with the spirit of your statement, which is to be precise and unambiguous.

Comment: @KevinLi How does one reconcile the triviality of $p(X)= P(X=X)=1$ and in the context of computing entropy when one may take $p(x)=P(X=x)$ and compute the average $-\mathbb{E}(\log p(X))$ which puts to use zoli's comment? The expectation is $\sum_i \log(p(x_i)) P(X=x_i)$ and clearly is not the trivial sum of $\sum_i \log(1)\cdot 1=0$. When we consider functions of random variables, PMFs and PDFs are not off-limits as choices for obtaining a new RV $Y=g(X)$ but they must be viewed as mere functions when doing so. Well, I think.

Comment: I was being extremely pedantic and had assigned different meanings to $ X$ and $ x $

Answer (score 1):

Well, *technically*, no, $P(A)$ is not the same thing as $P(A=a)$.   However, *however*, it is *convenient* to use a **shorthand notation**.

The expansions can get *cumbersome*, so reducing clutter is quite *useful*.   It becomes easier to follow the logic, and reducing typesetting reduces typographical erorrs.

So long as it is clear what the abbreviation represents, you *may* use it.